# Wrong redirects when using defaultRouter() for ModelViewSet in Django-REST-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, redirect, django-rest-viewsets

I have a Django Project where i made 3 Different Apps: "blog", "users", "api".
It is a Website where messages can be posted by using a model Post. I want to use an Django Rest API for accessing the Model. It works, but it messes with some redirects of the UpdateView and DeleteView of "blog". 
I think it could be a problem with using DefaultRouter() ?

When i try to use my blog/PostupdateView blog/PostDeleteView ( inherited from UpdateView and DeleteView) views, i keep getting redirected to **/api/blog/postid/** instead of just accessing my detailView where the path should be just **/blog/postid/** 
and i cannot figure out why.

**my Post Model:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**my Serializer:**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'content', 'date_posted', 'author', 'rooms')
```

**my api view for Post:**

```
  class PostView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Post.objects.all()
        serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

**My urls Files:**

main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('api/',include('api.urls')),
]
```

blog/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
   ...
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(),name='post-create'),
   ...
]
```

api/urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('post', views.PostView)

urlpatterns  = [
    path('',include(router.urls))
]
```

**my PostCreateView in blog/views.py**

```
class PostCreateView( LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'rooms']

    def test_func(self):
        ...

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
```

When using PostCreateView, i should be redirected to the detail-view of the created Post, as defined in the Post model. Instead im getting redirected to the api url that is generated by the router in api/urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easy methods to solve the issue is, change the **`get_absolute_url()`** method as

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/blog/{}/".format(self.pk)
```

---

## UPDATE

### What was the problem?

You are defined the URLs with the same name, **`post-detail`**, for API and usual view. You should name the URLs with unique names.

```
# blog/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='blog-post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='blog-post-create'),
    ...
]
#models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: this worked fine ! Thanks a lot ! can somebody explain what is wrong with using reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk}) ?

Answer (score 0):

I am new and can't comment, so I'll answer OP's question in the comment on the accepted answer, for anyone else who find this.

When you register a route with the default router, Django will automatically assign a set of url's for them, which are in the format `{basename}-{something else}`, where `{something else}` depends on what action you called and the HTTP method. The basename is determined by the `queryset` attribute of the viewset (so your basename would be `post`).

For "GET" + "retrieve" action, the url will be `{basename}-detail`, which for your queryset translated to `post-detail`, which overrides the `post-detail` you defined for the non-api view.

You can get around it by registering the router with a basename, so the non-api `post-detail` URL name will correspond to the `post/<pk>` URL, and `{other basename}-detail` can correspond to the API view:

```
router.register('post', views.PostView, basename='api-post')
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/